# Twitch Bot in Node JS log system

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitch

I'm working on a twitch bot in node.js and using tmi.js https://github.com/Schmoopiie/tmi.js

My problem is with the logging system I created. I think I'm misunderstanding node.js from the ground up here. I need to get the username from the chatter that just typed something.
This is my code:

```
client.on('chat', function (channel, user, message, self) {

    fs.open('logs/' + user +'.txt','r',function(err,fd){
    if (err && err.code=='ENOENT') 
    {
    fs.writeFile('logs/' + user +'.txt', '[' + 'GMT' + moment().format('Z ') + moment().format('D.M.YYYY H:mm:ss')  + '] ' + user + ': ' + message, function (err) {});
    } else {
    fs.appendFile('logs/' + user +'.txt', '[' + 'GMT' + moment().format('Z ') + moment().format('D.M.YYYY H:mm:ss')  + '] ' + user + ': ' + message + '\n', function(){});      
    }
    });

});
```

this triggers everytime a user types a message in chat. And I thought the variable "user" would have the value of the chatter that just typed something.

But the value of user is always `[object Object]`

Am I overlooking something? I can't find a way to get the username of the current chatter.

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: `user` is an object, inspect it with `console.log`.

Comment: you case use "user.username" instead of just "user"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I have any experience with tmi.js, but it appears the `user` variable you're getting there is an object, not a string. When you try to cast it to a string using `+`, you get [object Object] by default. Try doing this:

```
fs.appendFile('logs/' + JSON.stringify(user) +'.txt', '[' + 'GMT' + moment().format('Z ') + moment().format('D.M.YYYY H:mm:ss')  + '] ' + JSON.stringify(user) + ': ' + message + '\n', function(){});
```

or, even better, because you want that just for debugging:

```
console.log(user);
```

And check the console. It probably won't be pretty, but at least you'll be able to see what's inside the `user` variable. Perhaps it will be an object with a `username` property, and you'll be able to simply use `user.username`?

Comment: Alright thanks. I'm retarded. I can't believe how I missed that. user["username"] is working perfectly. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: As a tip, `user.username` is a better way to access such properties. The `myObject[myString]` notation is better used with dynamic strings, not static, such as in your `username` case.